# Memory issue when scanning and updating every row of a large table (sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I want to scan a large table with more than 1 million rows, meanwhile update one column of all rows to it.

Code below leads out of memory issue:

```
def main():
    session = Session()
    i = 0
    for row in session.query(article).yield_per(100):
        i = i + 1
        print(row.id)
        row.keywords = clean_tag(row.keywords)
        if i % 100 == 0:
            session.flush()
            session.expunge_all()
    session.commit()
```

As supposed, `flush()` will persist change of objects to database and expunge_all should remove these objects.

What's wrong?  Thanks.

---

edited on 7.17

As suggested by univerio I paste the example here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env
# coding=utf-8

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, BigInteger, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# engine = create_engine('mysql://root:123456@192.168.0.202/toutiao')
engine = create_engine('mysql://root:MyNewPass4!@192.168.3.220/toutiao')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=True)

Base = declarative_base()
class article(Base):
    # __tablename__ = 'ss_article_group'
    __tablename__ = 'article100'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    keywords = Column(String)

def clean_tag(tag):
    r"""
    >>> clean_tag('a,b\nc d')
    'a,b,c,d'
    >>> clean_tag('\na,b\n\n')
    'a,b'
    >>> clean_tag('a,b,')
    'a,b'
    >>> clean_tag(',')

    """
    if tag is None:
        return False
    tags = tag.split()
    new_tag = ','.join(tags)
    new_tag = new_tag.strip(',')
    if new_tag == '':
        return None
    if new_tag == tag:
        return False
    return new_tag

def main():
    session = Session()
    i = 0
    for row in session.query(article).yield_per(100):
        i = i + 1
        print(row.id)
        new_keywords = clean_tag(row.keywords)
        if new_keywords != False:
            row.keywords = new_keywords
        if i % 100 == 0:
            session.flush()
            session.expunge_all()
    session.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Which driver are you using?

Comment: @univerio The default mysql-python DBAPI.

Comment: Nothing is obviously wrong -- can you post your model definition as well as `clean_tag`?